# How to diagnose usb issue

Tags: usb

So my kern.log and syslog files filled up with tons of the below messages:

```
[514971.000109] phy0 -> rt2x00usb_vendor_request: Error - Vendor Request 0x07 failed for offset 0x30c4 with error -108
```

I was curious as to the steps to take, commands to run, places to look to help diagnose this issue (and curious as to what caused it)?

I'm guessing it's something USB elated. I had some issues with my printer earlier today so this might be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by a Realtek Wireless adapter that isn't very well supported.

Unfortunately, the only solution I could find is to get rid of it. If your wireless network is working properly, you can safely ignore the errors. If it's not, you should Ask a question about it, or see if it has already been asked.

Your wireless adapter identifies itself as rt2x00usb, and it's probably using the rt73usb kernel module. You can check what kernel modules are loaded by doing

```
modprobe -l | grep rtl.*usb
```

or

```
modprobe -l | grep rtl
```

If you don't use the card at all, you can add the kernel module to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (open the file by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`), this will prevent it from being loaded.

Have a look around this site if you do have wireless problems, there are quite a few question about Realtek adapters.