# USB ports unavailable after suspend

Tags: 12.04, usb, suspend, asus

My problem is that after installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, suspend did not work. Through [this training](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Asus_N53), I solved the suspend problem. But after resume from suspend my USB ports become unavailable.

Comment: Could u pls go through this post and find any useful info? http://askubuntu.com/questions/19356/how-to-diagnose-usb-issue

Comment: Have the same problem on a Lenovo Thinkpad x201. Would prefer any solution that does not require me to re-compile the kernel every time there is an update!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. And after a week of searching, I discovered what the problem was for me. In the Ubuntu kernel, the USB drivers are built-in. Therefore, upon suspend and resume, the drivers could not be unloaded and then reloaded as modules. So I had to compile the Linux kernel from source and made sure that the USB drivers (`xhci_hcd` and `ehci_hcd`) were made to be loadable modules.

From there, I created a file named `20_custom-ehci_hcd` in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`.

```shell
#!/bin/sh
# Inspired by http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9744970&postcount=19
#...and http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug
# Tidied by tqzzaa :)
VERSION=1.1
DEV_LIST=/tmp/usb-dev-list
DRIVERS_DIR=/sys/bus/pci/drivers
DRIVERS="ehci xhci" # ehci_hcd, xhci_hcd
HEX="[[:xdigit:]]"
MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=2
BIND_WAIT=0.1
unbindDev() {
  echo -n > $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
  for driver in $DRIVERS; do
    DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
    for dev in `ls $DDIR 2>/dev/null | egrep "^$HEX+:$HEX+:$HEX"`; do
      echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/unbind
      echo "$driver $dev" >> $DEV_LIST
    done
  done
}
bindDev() {
  if [ -s $DEV_LIST ]; then
    while read driver dev; do
      DDIR=$DRIVERS_DIR/${driver}_hcd
    while [ $((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS)) -gt 0 ]; do
      echo -n "$dev" > $DDIR/bind
      if [ ! -L "$DDIR/$dev" ]; then
        sleep $BIND_WAIT
      else
        break
      fi
      MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS=$((MAX_BIND_ATTEMPTS-1))
    done
  done fi
  rm $DEV_LIST 2>/dev/null
}
case "$1" in
  hibernate|suspend) unbindDev;;
  resume|thaw) bindDev;;
esac
```

I hope this works for you. I might have made another file somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

I found that other file. In `/etc/pm/config.d/`, I created a file called `modules`.

#### modules

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci ehci_hcd xhci_hcd xhci-hcd ehci-hcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution than rebuilding the kernel at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460790  I only needed the unbind/bind on my Asus N53SV

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that helped.

For me, I had to a) unbind the usb devices, and b) manually off the wifi.

In case somebody finds it useful, here is a):

root@tosh:~# cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_usb_suspend_fix

```
#!/bin/sh

LOGTAG=PwrUsbFix
UNDO=/var/run/pm-utils/pm-suspend/storage/rebind_usb.sh

# check am root
[ "$(id -u)" = 0 ] || {
    echo "$LOGTAG : must be run as root!"
    exit 1
    }

case "${1}" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        : > ${UNDO}
        find /sys/bus/pci/drivers -maxdepth 2 -path \*\[eu\]hci\* -name unbind | cut -d\/ -f -6 | \
            while read BUS ; do 
                find ${BUS} -maxdepth 1 -type l -name 00\* | \
                    while read DEVPATH ; do
                        DEVICE=`basename $DEVPATH`
                        echo "$LOGTAG : echo ${DEVICE} > ${BUS}/unbind"
                        echo -n "${DEVICE}" > ${BUS}/unbind
                        echo "echo \"${LOGTAG} ${DEVICE} > ${BUS}/bind\"" >> ${UNDO}
                        echo "echo -n \"${DEVICE}\" > ${BUS}/bind" >> ${UNDO}
                    done
            done
    ;;
    resume|thaw)
        . ${UNDO}
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

and b)

root@tosh# cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/30_wifi_off

```
#! /bin/sh

MODULES="ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath"

case "${1}" in
        hibernate|suspend)
              # Switch wireless off
              nmcli nm sleep true
              rfkill block 0
              rmmod ${MODULES}
        ;;
        resume|thaw)
              # Switch wireless on
              modprobe ${MODULES}
              rfkill unblock 0
              nmcli nm sleep false
        ;;
esac
```

finally - sys info..

```
http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-pro-p300-28e/

root@tosh:~# uname -a
Linux tosh 3.13.0-31-generic #55~precise2-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 2 17:02:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@tosh:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:    precise
```