# Wireless mouse temporarily freezes (sleeps) on battery power

Tags: 12.04, mouse, suspend

I have been getting a very annoying problem since recently in Ubuntu 12.04, probably due to another update that did more bad than good...

When I resume from sleep on battery power my Lenovo Thinkpad T420, my wireless laser mouse (Logitech M705) freezes everytime I leave it for 2 seconds. It then starts moving again when I shake it for 5 seconds. The touchpad works normally.

I'm guessing the mouse enters some sleep mode and I'd like to know where to change this "timeout" value.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution on this page:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1675277

here's what I did:

in /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf

```
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0
```

And everything works normal now.

Comment: Did you have to reboot for this to work?

Comment: I rebooted, and it appears to have worked. I guess there's probably a way to restart it without rebooting, but I've always had trouble find out stuff like that for USB. Anyway, thanks for the research!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which kernel module the mouse drivers are using (you could check that). There's the possibility to mark modules problematic to suspend/resume, having them removed at suspend - and reloaded at resume. This is done using the `SUSPEND_MODULES` setting, as e.g. described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130562/usb-ports-unavailable-after-suspend). Worth trying.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, I've just edited the question, it no longer is a suspend/resume problem but a problem occurring only on battery power.

Comment: Oh -- I see. But your new description seems even more annoying: 5s after resume only is something one can live with, but in the middle of work... Good luck for a fast solution!