# How can I disable USB autosuspend for a specific device?

Tags: usb, power-management, powertop

This is related to the issue discussed in [Wireless mouse temporarily freezes (sleeps) on battery power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161657/wireless-mouse-temporarily-freezes-sleeps-on-battery-power).

Summary: the mouse freezes when operating on battery since it is autosuspended after a certain time and needs more time to wake up.

Disabling USB autosuspend for the mouse's receiver in [PowerTOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerTOP#Hardware) is a temporary solution, but it does not survive a reboot.

**How can I permanently disable the USB autosuspend for only *one specific* device?**

A solution that does not involve installing additional packages is preferred (after all, I want to *disable* something), but it is not required. Removing PowerTOP (which seems to be a solution for some) is not what I want - I like PowerTOP...

And installing `laptop-mode-tools` to disable USB autosuspend altogether is not what I want, either, thus the new question.

Also: Will this affect the battery of my notebook? The Logitech unifying receiver for the mouse stays connected all the time, so if that prevents the autosuspend from happening for all devices that would probably be bad.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)**

```
sudo apt install tlp
sudo lsusb
```

Find the USB device's input id - it should look like `1234:5678`.

Edit the file `sudo vi /etc/default/tlp` and add your device's input ID to `USB_BLACKLIST` by adding the following line with your device's input id like so:

```
USB_BLACKLIST="1234:5678"
```

**Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)**

As mentioned [here at hecticgeek.com](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/06/fix-usb-mouse-not-working-laptop-mode-tools-ubuntu/), the trick consists of two parts:

Using `lsusb` to ascertain the device IDs of the USB devices you wish to disable autosuspend for.

And then adding them to `AUTOSUSPEND_USBID_BLACKLIST` in the `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf` (`usb-autosuspend.conf` until Ubuntu 14.04) configuration file (details are well documented in there as well).

Comment: Actually my mouse got lost/stolen shortly after, so I cannot test this.
But judging from the `.conf` file this is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for :)

Comment: Looks like it's `AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST` now (Ubuntu 17.04)

Comment: Dell's Ubuntu laptops with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS have `tlp` installed rather than `laptop-mode-tools`, so if you want to blacklist USB devices from being put into autosuspend mode on these laptops, set the `USB_BLACKLIST` setting in the file `/etc/default/tlp` - the changes take place immediately

Comment: HIDs are already blacklisting from tlp:
/etc/default/tlp
# Note: input devices (usbhid) are excluded automatically (see below)
#USB_BLACKLIST="045e:07a5"

Comment: The TLP documentation mentions that it’s a power management for *laptops* (more specifically ThinkPad). Does it work for desktop PCs?

Comment: On TLP 1.5 The list name is `USB_DENYLIST="1111:2222 3333:4444"`

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem with PCs on an [Avocent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocent) [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch), where laptop-mode-tools was not installed (and didn't want to solve it that way in any case). In my case, autosuspending the KVM made the keyboard and mouse behave erratically (after a few seconds idle, they'd suspend and lose input data for a while until enough clicks and shakes woke them up).

When I ran [PowerTOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerTOP#Hardware) and toggled USB autosuspend off for the Avocent, PowerTOP told me the command to disable it from the command line was:

```
echo 'on' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-10/power/control'
```

The '3-10' bit will be different on different systems. I'm not sure how to determine that other than running PowerTOP, but there's probably some way.

Instead, I used a [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rule to match the product id of my device:

trent+14.04:/etc/udev/rules.d$ cat 10-usb-avocent-kvm-pm.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0624", ATTR{idProduct}=="0013", ATTR{product}=="SC Secure KVM", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}:="on"
```

To get the proper udev information I ran:

```
udevadm info -a --path /sys/bus/usb/devices/N-N
```

Comment: This answer helped me stop USB autosuspend causing my Logitech webcam to make me sound like a chipmunk on Skype.  This was on a desktop where installing `laptop-mode-tools` was inappropriate.  I was not able, however, to get udev to write to `power/control` on boot, but was able to accomplish the same thing by setting the autosuspend delay to -1: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0809", TEST=="power/autosuspend", ATTR{power/autosuspend}:="-1"`

Answer (score 7):

In `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/usb-autosuspend.conf` you will find:

```
# Enable USB autosuspend feature?
# Set to 0 to disable
CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND="auto"
```

You should change it to `CONTROL_USB_AUTOSUSPEND="0"`.

This will automatically make any USB device have the value "on" in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/"DEVICE ID"/power/control`. This will make the value of the autosuspend files inactive:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/"DEVICE ID"/power/autosuspend
2
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/"DEVICE ID"/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
2000
```

Answer (score 6):

The power options for a USB device are in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/n-n/power`. Unfortunately, what n-n is for a given device takes some sleuthing to find out, so I think this will prove a stumbling block when it comes to having a script that automatically does

```
echo -1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/autosuspend
```

to turn off autosuspend on that device. The magic n-n does actually appear in the output of

```
udevadm info --export-db
```

so I think udev will be your friend here; some kind of udev script keyed on a parameter that identifies your mouse, then runs a script that echos -1 into the relevant file.

Comment: Will this survive a reboot? echoing into /sys seems to be non-permanent, isn't it?

Comment: Put the command in your /etc/rc.local before the 'exit 0' line

Comment: I have written this [gist](https://gist.github.com/weshouman/c9d6e8e1e875b15928005a70fedb14fa) as an automation for getting the magic number `n-n` given the device `vendor:product` id

Answer (score 4):

I created my own [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rule:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0cf3", ATTR{idProduct}=="3004", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus), I found a solution in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf`:

```
# Auto-Suspend timeout in seconds
# Number of seconds after which the USB devices should suspend
AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT=1800
```

It was originally set for `2` for me. 30 minutes is far more reasonable.

After the change, do:

```
sudo service laptop-mode restart
```

I am still not sure how to fully disable it, but this is fine for me now.