# Problem with HD being ejected without aparent reason

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd, totem

I don't know how to describe the error properly, but I will try...

Well, I have a folder with music in a external HD, and without any visible pattern, after a few minutes, Totem complains that it couldn't find a file and stops playing... and I can see that the external HD was ejected and re-opened, automatically. The file is there and if I remove it from list and put it back, it plays without error.

But, a few minutes later, that happens with another file.

I've noted that just happens when Totem is playing. Ie, when it's not, the HD isn't ejected like I described above.

It's not a big problem... but as an ADHD, it is ANNOYING! And I loose any little concentration I have. =/

I'll be glad with any help you can do.

EDIT: Totem doesn't have this behavior when playing something from an internal drive.

EDIT2:

```
[250038.025865] usb 3-7: USB disconnect, device number 5
[250038.294329] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[250038.311120] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211
[250038.311125] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[250038.311127] usb 3-7: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[250038.311644] hub 3-7:1.0: USB hub found
[250039.189346] usb 3-7.3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[250039.207010] usb 3-7.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[250039.207019] usb 3-7.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[250039.240416] cdc_acm 3-7.3:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[250039.240909] cdc_acm 3-7.3:1.3: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[250039.242029] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[260135.453428] usb 3-7.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
[262544.679407] usb 4-6: USB disconnect, device number 3
[262550.249081] usb 4-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[262550.265565] usb 4-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3320
[262550.265568] usb 4-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[262550.267500] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[263424.681075] usb 4-6: USB disconnect, device number 4
[263430.238678] usb 4-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[263430.255124] usb 4-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3320
[263430.255127] usb 4-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[263430.257019] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

EDIT 3:

```
[265932.192333] usb 4-6: USB disconnect, device number 5
[265936.810873] usb 4-6: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[265937.330229] usb 4-6: device not accepting address 5, error -22
[265937.390152] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[265937.390155] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[265937.390156] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[265937.390157] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[265937.390157] Read(10): 28 00 0c 8d 15 a6 00 00 1e 00
[265937.390161] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1684581680
[265937.390163] quiet_error: 24 callbacks suppressed
[265937.390165] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570662
[265937.390169] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570663
[265937.390170] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570664
[265937.390171] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570665
[265937.390181] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570666
[265937.390182] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570667
[265937.390183] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570668
[265937.390184] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570669
[265937.390185] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570670
[265937.390186] Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570671
[265937.390196] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[265937.390267] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[265937.390269] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[265937.390270] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[265937.390270] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[265937.390271] Read(10): 28 00 0c 8d 15 c4 00 00 02 00
[265937.390274] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1684581920
[265937.390637] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[265937.434292] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[265937.463208] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[265937.463233] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[265937.463234] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[265937.463835] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8803bb9b0180
[265937.463837] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8803bb9b01c0
[265937.490220] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc7-8.
[265937.769847] usb 4-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[265937.786275] usb 4-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3320
[265937.786277] usb 4-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[265937.786279] usb 4-6: Product: Expansion Desk
[265937.786280] usb 4-6: Manufacturer: Seagate
[265937.786280] usb 4-6: SerialNumber: NA4KCLH6
[265937.788112] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[265937.788255] scsi13 : usb-storage 4-6:1.0
[265938.785918] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion Desk   0711 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[265938.786301] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[265938.786420] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 976754645 4096-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)
[265938.786652] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[265938.786659] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[265938.786886] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[265938.787290] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 976754645 4096-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)
[265938.834613]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 < sdc5 sdc6 sdc7 >
[265938.835176] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] 976754645 4096-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)
[265938.835572] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[265939.353284] EXT4-fs (sdc6): recovery complete
[265939.353288] EXT4-fs (sdc6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[265939.431369] systemd-hostnamed[27579]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[265939.558187] EXT4-fs (sdc7): recovery complete
[265939.637121] EXT4-fs (sdc7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[266359.814175] show_signal_msg: 23 callbacks suppressed
[266359.814178] compiz[2784]: segfault at 2ed6fbb0 ip 00007fafc1db9cc3 sp 00007fffbef3dc98 error 4 in libunityshell.so[7fafc1b89000+57f000]
[266360.701145] QXcbEventReader[4254]: segfault at 7f8340eeb879 ip 00007f8340eeb879 sp 00007f833f48fe10 error 14 in locale-archive[7f83411e0000+6e4000]
[266361.825235] TVGuiDelegate[2976]: segfault at 8e98000 ip 00000000f55d0f96 sp 00000000f45fd5b8 error 4 in libc-2.19.so[f5554000+1a8000]
[266362.644744] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: irq 68 for MSI/MSI-X
[269865.023646] systemd-hostnamed[30808]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[270682.350363] systemd-hostnamed[30888]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

Comment: Anything relevant in the system logfiles?

Comment: @Jan nothing, I think... dmesg seems ok, like e-HD was ejected and back again, but no errors. =/
I'll edit and paste part of it... maybe you can see something that I missing there...

Comment: There are roughly 15 minutes between `[262550.267500] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected` and the disconnect `[263424.681075] usb 4-6: USB disconnect, device number 4`... Maybe it's some kind of powersave stuff shutting down the disc after 15 minutes?

Comment: @Jan When Totem isn't playing, I didn't observed this behavior... sometimes I move like 250Gb from one drive to another, and never had problem of it being shutdown in the middle. 
I don't discard what you said... but I don't know how I could test it. 
Can you suggest me some test?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/370406/167115

Comment: @mchid I'm trying this... I hope it works! =]
Just to note and be sure, I've found the file inside "/sys/bus/usb/devices/".

Answer (score 1):

#### New answer based on latest edit

```
Buffer I/O error on device sdc1, logical block 210570671
```

This message may indicate that the drive is about to fail.

**First of all: Make backups if you not have done it yet!**
Then check the reallocated sector count (smartmontools). If you see reallocated sectors, you should IMHO change the drive ASAP:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdc
```

Also run a check on your filesystem (don't know which FS you use on that disc)...

#### Old answer

Please check the output of the following command:

```
for d in /sys/bus/usb/devices/[0-9]* ; do if [[ -e $d/product ]] ; then echo -e "`basename $d`\t`cat $d/power/control`\t`cat $d/speed`\t`cat $d/product`" ; fi ; done
```

The second column will display if auto-suspend is allowed (auto) or disabled (on)...

Comment: I think the line about e-HD would be "4-6 on 5000 Expansion Desk"

Comment: I've pasted a new dmesg out... I think now the error appeared...

Comment: Still not working... =/