# 14.04 USBs powered off at login screen

Tags: 14.04, usb, power-management, login-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a Dell normal desktop PC. I've been suffering this issue from the very beggining.

Randomly, the USBs ports seem disconnected/powered off at the login screen, before any access to the system. Sometimes the machines boots properly and everything works as expected. But others, the mouse and keyboards turn off (lights off) and I have to perform a hard power off and power on again.

I tried to plug other USB devices and they showed no power input.

I guess it is some kernel configuration that presents some problem with the hardware, and tried to set the autosuspend and autosuspend_delay_ms to -1, but this didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not because of inactivity. What I would try to do would be to install the powertop package in software-center or by `sudo apt-get install powertop` then run sudo powertop and for all usb devices in tunables set it so it says bad while this may use a tiny bit more power it will stop the power managment from switching off usb devices. This questoin could provide more insight on this but this sounds like a usb power managemnt problem. Also since this happens at the login screen this could be it is at inactivity which is why you see no reason for it and appears random to you but it is not. [How can I disable usb-autosuspend for a specific device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device) is also likely to help you.