# Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 - Realtek USB Wifi not powering on after sleep

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, suspend, realtek

I have one nagging problem on my laptop. I'm using a USB Wifi adapter from Realtek. When I wake the computer from sleep, the USB adapter does not power on. It's not blinking. If I unplug and plug it back in, it powers on and connects to my network.

Is there any fix or workaround for this? Any script I can run on wake-up that resets the specific USB-port I'm using for the adapter?

I'm at work now so I don't have the kernel module code etc. I can get it later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One program I like for fixing usb power management and several other settings is powertop. you need to run it in a terminal with sudo powertop move over to tunables and try to turn your USB wifi to bad to disable powermangement after you turn it on.

If this works for you and you want to make it permanent for every time see [How can I disable usb-autosuspend for a specific device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device)