# Mouse cursor freezing randomly for 5 seconds

Tags: mouse, 18.04, gnome-shell

I have just upgraded from **17.10** to **18.04**. Every went *smoothly* but now **my mouse cursor randomly freeze for about 5 seconds**.

I was using **Gnome Shell on Wayland**. And I got no problem (except some lags here and then which seems to be gone); now I am still using it and I have that problem.

Moreover, I tried Gnome Shell on **Xorg** and the problem is stil there !

I tried changing the graphics driver (the intel one aka i965) by using a more up to date one by using the PPA *oibaf*. It also changed nothing.

I have not tried yet **Unity** but ....

- I have changed the battery of the mouse, still no change.
- I have changed the USB port the receiver of the wireless mouse is in, still no change.
- I will try another mouse but I don't expect it to be different because all was fine before the upgrade and not now.

It is really the mouse freezing only and not the **display** because I let running *glxgears* while a froze happen, and the wheels were still spinning.

Comment: This works fine in the Ubuntu Live USB 18.04 or Archlinux

Comment: This works fine in a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04. I had to do it. I couldn't continue with those random freeze every minute.

Comment: Are you using external USB mouse? I experienced pauses in external USB devices when after I run powertop with --auto-tune. For my case, the devices is being put to sleep/wakeup and this is behaving like they freeze if not moved constantly. If you see this behaviour, it could be because of overly agressive power saving option.

Comment: Are there any clues in dmseg or any logs? Sounds like a USB bus stall and reset.

Comment: Is it possible to test with a corded ('hard-wired') mouse to compare whether you get the same issue? Might help to narrow down the source of the problem (e.g. if it still happens with the corded mouse then it's definitely not anything to do with Bluetooth)

Comment: I had a similar symptom (wasn't a [power issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113332/349837)) using an external USB 3.0 HDD. Probably have something to do with IRQs or how evdev and/or (newer) [libinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Via_xinput) handle mouses.

Comment: I had this same problem a while back. It is power saving for sure. It has nothing to do with the display. The USB bus is being put to sleep. i'll just assume this is a laptop. Does it do it when plugged in? Does a wired mouse experience the same issue? Here's an answer with about fifty ways to disable the powers saving in Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse

Comment: I guess, this question is related to question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029256/keyboard-input-lag-in-ubuntu-18-04, quoting from there "It could be USB3.0 issue". Still discussion is going on.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to interference, it is unlikely to be connected with wasps, try using a wired mouse for a while, if the problem is resolved, then search near the computer for what can cause interference data, a receiver, a phone, anything.

Comment: My mouse wat too far from the USB reciever