# Strange graphics issue after upgrading to 18.04 that affects only one user account

Tags: xorg, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, window-manager

After upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04, I started experiencing a strange graphics issue: text and background in scrollable parts of some windows were getting "scrambled".  I performed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1 when it became available (formatting the system partitions), but this did not resolve the problem.

However, I cannot reproduce this problem in a fresh account, even if I copy over my entire `dconf` configuration!  I also tried resetting the `dconf` configuration in the affected account and disabling (all) GNOME Shell extensions, but it did not help.

The problem appears usually when I try to scroll the text in a scrollable area or resize the window.  Maybe other parts of windows are also affected.  Sometimes the problem appears immediately on opening a window.

When I scroll a scrollable area or resize the whole window, text and background get scrambled by overlapping on themselves.  Sometimes black or transparent areas appear.  [GNOME Calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Calculator) 3.28.2 and [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg) 3.26 windows are strongly affected.  With GNOME Calculator the issue it the easiest to reproduce -- it suffices to launch it.

Which system or user settings could cause such problem?

I am attaching pictures which show the problem.

[image: Glitch in GNOME Calculator]

[image: Glitch in Software Update]

I have Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2).

By the way, 3D gaming works fine.

---

**Things I tried that did not help:**

1. `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel`,
2. `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
3. Reinstall Ubuntu 18.04.1 completely.
4. `dconf reset -f /` and disable GNOME Shell extensions.

Comment: Useless comment: don't fight it. Just reinstall. I had that issue https://askubuntu.com/q/1031549/350004 and gave up and reinstall a fresh ubuntu.

Comment: have you installed graphics drivers? what is your graphics card?

Comment: My update today installed "intel-firmware-microcode"... I wonder if that would do anything for you? I swear I have had this happen to me before and it was a driver of some sort that fixed it. What is your lsmod and lspci output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to clean up a bit some abandoned "dot-files" in my home folder (the home directory of the affected account) and managed to resolve the problem.

The problem was caused by my `.xinputrc` file that contained a single line of code:

```
run_im xim
```

In comments it was saying that it was created by [`im-config`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-im-config/).  (I do not remember why I executed `im-config`.)  After I removed this file, the glitches were gone.

---

*Update.* It seems that the file got automatically regenerated with the following content:

```
# im-config(8) generated on Sun, 29 Jul 2018 09:11:43 +0200
run_im ibus
# im-config signature: 1badc17f2a2c24108e97cd2fd412e476  -
```

There is currently no problems with this new content.  (I am not sure if the file was regenerated by Ubuntu.)

Comment: I guess you've changed input method because of keyboard shortcut clashes (like ctrl+shift+u for example). Applying this solution will help for the glitches but also will bring the keyboard issues back. I love Linux o_O

Answer (score 3):

I had the same graphical issues in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (after upgrading from version 16.04.5 to 18.04.1), only the following command solved the problems:

```
$ dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

Comment: As i mentioned, `dconf reset` did not work for me.

Comment: I m experiencing the same issue and so far "dconf reset" did not work neither.

Answer (score 2):

**Reinstall the Drivers**

Per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers)r try reinstalling intel drivers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

If this doesn't work, you might be able to fix it by tweaking settings with intel goodies:

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode inteltool intel-gpu-tools
```

But I don't know how to use them so you are on your own. [Here is a reference manual for intel-gpu-tools](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/igt/) and you can always read the manpages. eg

```
man intel-gpu-tools
```

Comment: I tried the first three commands, they didn't help.  gitg windows are still scrambled.

Comment: is it just gitg? did you reinstall that? did you install xserver-xorg-video-intel and reboot? did you install intel-microcode?

Comment: Everything is the same. I installed `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and rebooted, and i already had `intel-microcode` (but i would be quite surprised if it was related).

Answer (score 2):

When you run `update-initramfs` you should not be getting error messages for missing skylake drivers.

#### Under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.34-041434-generic
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin
```

#### Under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin
```

In particular you should be seeing the last line. If not follow the instructions here: [Updated kernel to 4.8 now missing firmware warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings/832528#832528)

Comment: I tried, thanks.  The only line it printed was: `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic`.

Comment: In fact, i used to see the warning mentioned in the [question you linked](https://askubuntu.com/q/832524) in previous versions of Ubuntu (before my graphics issues), but i haven't noticed them so far in 18.04.  I understand that those warnings with `kbl` are not relevant to me because they are about Kaby Lake

Comment: @Alexey OK. But did you run `update-iniitramfs` above and see the Skylake driver (`skl_guc_ver9_33.bin`)added?

Comment: As i said, it only printed one line.

Comment: @Alexey You might want to add the Skylake driver then. I can't say if it will fix the problem though.

Comment: Could you tell me please how i can check that i do not have it already?  Is it because i do not see this second line printed by `update-initramfs`?

Comment: @Alexey on my system it shows up using `ll /lib/firmware/i915/`

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you still have the problem, but i experienced the same bug while using Ubuntu 18.04.2 with  Ubuntu Wayland. Switching back to Ubuntu from Ubuntu Wayland after reboot solved my problem.

Comment: The solution that i described in my answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my setting in "Settings>Region & language>Manage Installed Languages>language>Keyboard input method system" to "XIM" in order to make short cuts of a software developing tool (Intellij IDEA) work correctly but it makes this problem and changing to "IBus" and rebooting resolved the issue.