# USB port not working after resume from suspend - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, suspend, lenovo

My USB ports and webcam are not working after sleep. I have WiFi, but that's it.

I am Ubuntu 14.04 and I have usb2.0, usb3.0, webcam.
I found similar case [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130562/usb-ports-unavailable-after-suspend) and [here](http://vital.org.nz/entry/title/usb_problems_on_resume_from_suspend_with_ubuntu_1310_saucy) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1968487), but none gave me working answer.

`lsusb` after resume:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb` before resume:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I get my USB working after resume from suspend?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a confirmed open bug reported in March last year (2014) that is probably causing your problem. [READ HERE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1291969)

In the bug report are many users reporting they have Nouveau or Nvidia drivers installed, so it might or might not be related to this.

There are workarounds, none of them acceptable.But i would turn-off the sleep function for the time being, or run 'apt-get dist-upgrade' and upgrade to the latest release while hoping it will not carry the bug upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using BlackBerry cellphone OS 6.0, connected via usb-cable to PC.

I'm testing this Fix by Hardware adjustment:

1. While the PC is OFF, going to physical Motherboard* to JUSB_PW# (USB
   power Jumper for rear or front USB 2.0 ports), shifting jumper I
   keep USB power from VCC5 to 5VSB mode.

   5VSB does USB ports provide power in Standby mode.

   After Suspend S3 (to Ram) and Resume "Linux Mint 17.3 Mate" (based
   on Ubuntu 14.04), the Blackberry SD devices continue mounted and
   working like a charm.

   Still, I've not tried back the USB power Jumper to VCC5 on
   Motherboard*.

   - MSI 760GM-P34 (FX) - AMI BIOS v.2013-04-28.

If the Above worked, this paragraph could be skipped:
Previously to step 1., from physical Motherboard* while the PC is OFF(!!), I cleaned the CMOS RAM Battery by placing a jumper there, and seconds after removing or opening this jumper.

*Do not clear the CMOS RAM while the system is ON because it will damage the mainboard.*

---

Since ms windows, I never had missing usb devices, after resume system.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and the solution that worked for me is the following:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Then update your grub config

```
sudo update-grub
```